# Does the time-independent Schrodinger equation has an exact and general solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

The Schrodinger equation (time-independent) is for sure the most important equation in quantum mechanics;

$$-\frac{ℏ^2}{2m}∇^2ψ(x)+V(x)ψ(x)=Eψ(x)$$

let consider the one-dimensional equation;

$$\frac{d^2ψ(x)}{dx^2}-\frac{2m}{ℏ^2}(V(x)-E)ψ(x)=0$$

Is there any exact general eignvalue-eignfucntion solution for such equation? And if it's not possible to get the exact eignvalue-eignfucntion solution, can the equation be solved in a pure mathematical sense? Where we can  rewrite the equation as;

$$\frac{d^2ψ(x)}{dx^2}+ S(x)ψ(x)=0$$

wherein $S(x)=-\frac{2m}{ℏ^2}(V(x)-E)$. I'm not talking here about the WKB approximation method, I'm talking about an exact and general solution, so does this equation has analytical solutions?

Comment: It depends, what is your $V$? Each $V$ gives you a distinct PDE. Even if we put them under the umbrella of one Schrodinger equation, there isn't *one* equation in this context.

Comment: For some potentials there is no solution. See  [The Inverse Cube Force Law, John Baez](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/inverse_cube.html) - Quantum aspects